# Expected value for European Roulette Probability

Tags: probability

below is the query to calculate expected value?

[image]

Probabilities P(x)= 1/37 = 0.0270   P'(x)=1-1/37=0.9729
 Expected value=100 * 0.0270-0.9729*100 for betting 100 $ on number 5,

What could be wrong with the solutions above.. Thank you..

Comment: It's better if you can share the whole question.

Comment: This is the full question, Where European roulette is the Casino game where there are possible outcomes from 0-36 in a round fashion

Comment: There seems to be some other text related to this question because in the text it says, "if she plays" (who is she?), "this game" (where does it explain the game?), and the explanation starts with 'Now, ' (what was it saying before "Now"?). 

Although it might be obvious sometimes, it's always better having self-sufficient questions. I'm asking because I'm seeing no fault in the expected value calculation of yours.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your solution is that winning Roulette with a bet placed on a single number pays out 36x the bet, not 2x. The solution is therefore:
$$(3600 - 100) * \frac{1}{37} + (0 - 100) * \frac{36}{37} = -2.70$$

Comment: (+1) This is the missing piece I was asking to OP.

Comment: Could you pls clarify, Any number  can be selected for bet as 1/37? how this comes as 36x? , for not selecting other 36 , it should be 36/37